# Variant of the Halting Problem

Tags: proof-verification, computational-complexity

S = {$<A, B, k>$ : there are less than k natural numbers n for which A(x), B(x) both halt}

I have the following proof that S is undecidable.

Suppose D($<A, B, k>$) is a decider for S. Define the following:

halts(P, i) {
$\quad$define A(x) {
$\quad \quad$P(i)
$\quad \quad$if x in (1, 2) then return else loop
$\quad$}

$\quad$define B(x) {
$\quad \quad$P(i)
$\quad \quad$if x in (1, 2) then return else loop
$\quad$}

$\quad$ if $\;D(<A,B,3>)\;\;$accepts then
$\quad \quad$ halts
$\quad$ else
$\quad \quad$ loops
}

If D exists then we would be able to decide if P halts on i. Since the Halting Problem is undecidable, D cannot exist and hence S is undecidable.

I believe that the same argument can be used to show that S is unrecognizable with D being a recognizer instead of a decider. Am I correct?

Or is there a better way to show that S is unrecognizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $n$ and $x$ in your definition of $S$ are supposed to be the same, and if I'm interpreting your program correctly, then your halts(P,i) will halt if and only if $P(i)$ doesn't. So you seem to be building into your construction part of the proof of the undecidability of the halting problem.

In my opinion, it would be simpler (and would provide a complete proof) to observe that one standard version of the halting problem is Turing reducible to $S$ (in fact, many-one reducible to the complement of $S$) as follows. A Turing machine $A$ (with no input, or, if you prefer, with a dummy input $x$) halts if and only if there are *not* less than $1$ numbers $x$ for which $A$ and $A$ both halt.

Comment: Yes, n and x are supposed to be the same. It was a typo. In halts(P, i), A and B are defined as subprograms with the property that <A, B, 3> is in S iff P(i) halts. A and B are never executed by halts(P,i). Their definitions are passed to D. So, if D accepts <A, B, 3> it means that P(i) halts. So, the existence of D would allow the construction of halts(P, i) which is a solution to the Halting Problem.

Comment: As for your second point about reducing to the complement of S. If I understand correctly, this would mean that the complement of S is recognizable. Since S is undecidable, this would have to mean that S is unrecognizable. Is my interpretation of your comments correct?

Comment: The reduction shows that $S$ is not computably enumerable (which I guess is what you mean by "recognizable"), because the complement of the halting problem is not computably enumerable. (Your earlier comment, that $A$ and $B$ are never executed by halts(P,i), confirms one aspect of my guess as to the intended meaning of your program.)

Comment: $S_1$ = {(A, B, 0) : A(x) and B(x) both do not halt}  
$S_2$ = {(A, B, k) : A(x) and B(x) both halt on the same set of k natural numbers}   
In the definition of S, for k = 1 we get $S_1$    
$S_2$ covers any other k, which means $S = S_1 \;U\; S_2$    
(Note: if A and B both halt on less than k inputs, they certainly both halt on less than $\infty$ inputs)

If I understood your definition of "not less than 1" correctly, it would be equivalent to $S_2$. So, we have not defined the complement of S.  
Is my interpretation of S correct? Could you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @user137481 "Less than 1 natural number" means "no natural numbers." So (A,A,1) is in S if and only if there is no natural number such that A(x) andA(x) both halt. Since the A(x) in my answer is independent of x, that's equivalent to "A doesn't halt."

Comment: So, formally we would first assume that a recognizer R for S exists. If so, R would be able to recognize (A, A, 1) which is a machine(s) that never halt. But this is the complement of the Halting Problem which is unrecognizable. Hence R cannot exist. Is my interpretation of your answer correct?

Comment: Yes, your summary is correct.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things. Thank you.